# Azure DevOps & Logic Apps: Attach file to work item

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to start with LogicApp - no prior experience.

I have a DevOps project and LogicApps workflow. Workflow is triggered by received mail and creates a new work item in DevOps.

If the email contains any attachments, workflow creates a blob, retrieves the blob, and then **I'd like to attach the file to a work item**, but I have no idea how.

[Workflow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eRp2.png)

How Can I do that? I couldn't find any option in 'Update a work item' action:

[Work Item action block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhClK.png)

Is there any way how to do it via 'Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps' action block?

[Sent an HTTP request to Azure DevOps action block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DOii.png)

Comment: Hello! have you had a chance to explore the answer I gave you? If it satisfies you or answers your question please vote up or mark aa answer whichever is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be possible through the Azure DevOps REST API, using the [Work Item - Create Attachment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

You can use this URI format and replace the placeholders accordingly. The Microsoft document will give you more information about what each mean and also the value type expected there.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName={fileName}&uploadType={uploadType}&areaPath={areaPath}&api-version=6.0
```

We're actually using the Azure DevOps API for other Pipeline actions but instead of using the built in `Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps`, we're using the generic `HTTP Connector`. You will also need to authenticate using an account that has access to the project.